# SQL Insert - Msg 207 Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

The issue is that I am trying to insert some data into my SQL server database, but for some reason I keep getting the infamous "invalid column name" error, and nothing is inserted as a result.

Now, I believe I know WHY (sort of) this is happening, as I am trying to insert a value that is based on the value of a field in another column using a case query, but I'm not sure I'm really doing this right - see the codes:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table_name(points, discount)
VALUES
(3, CASE WHEN (points = 6) THEN 0.5 WHEN (points = 12) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END
```

I am getting the invalid column name on the "points" column. It is definitely there so am I correct in thinking that my query is not right, or that I should be going about this a different way?

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 - not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Where is the `(points = 6)` and `(points = 12)` coming from?  What `points` are you trying to reference?  I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: sorry I think I've probably confused it a bit... I want the discount value to be either 0, 0.5 or 1.0 depending on the value of the points field, again I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing with the case...

Comment: But in your example, you are inserting every row with a points value of `3`, so nothing will ever have a `points` value of `6` or `12`.  Are you trying to do an update?  Maybe you should post your table structure some sample data and then the desired result of your query.

Comment: oh I see, no this is just one line I've posted as an example, there are several others after this with different values for points (i.e. 5, 6, 12 etc).

Comment: Please edit your original post with some sample data and the desired result, it will help solve your problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think I got my answer below ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number 3 in VALUES section did not yet become 'points' column, so you can't reference it like this in your CASE statement. You could rewrite your query to something like that:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table_name(points, discount)
select 
    x.points
    ,CASE WHEN (x.points = 6) THEN 0.5 WHEN (x.points = 12) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END as discount
from (
    select 3 as points union all
    select 12
) x
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I didn't fully understand the use of select when inserting, so I think I will need to do a little research into this :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this business logic that you want to be able to enforce somehow? If so then it looks to me like you are possibly looking for a calculated column.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
( 
    ID INT,
    Points INT,
    Discount AS CASE WHEN (Points = 6) THEN 0.5 WHEN (Points = 12) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END
)
```

This way whatever data you insert into the table will always conform to those rules.

Inserts now become real simple:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Points) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO table_name (Points) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO table_name (Points) VALUES(12);
```